# Recovering files from Git objects

Tags: git, object, recovery

I obliterated all my work and would prefer not to explain how. 
 The only thing I have left are the git objects. More then anything I would like to recover some of the loss packed Image files. From the size of the object files I can tell which ones they are. Is there a way to turn them back into usable files?

Comment: only git objects? no refs/branches/tags? first thing: backup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## first thing: make a backup! then work on a copy of that backup.

if the git objects are still in the correct directory (`.git/objects/xx/xxx…`) you can use `git fsck --full` for git to discover them — it will probably list every object in your repository. now look for the ones labeled `commit` and `tag`, those are the ones you want to recover.

i would probably use a script which creates a branch for each commit object found (e.g. simply increnting numbers `rescue-1`, `rescue-2`, etc.). afterwards use `gitk --all` to visualize all your branches and pick the top (most recent) one. create a new branch there `rescued-master`.

checkout your new master branch and run `git branch --no-merge`. you should get a list of branched  off commits, not contained in master. you probably want to give them a new branch name too.

after you're done, delete all the numbered `rescue-` branches.

hope that helps and gives a a starting point.