# Recover files deleted by git

Tags: git

I wanted to stash changes to an untracked file, and following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835501/how-do-you-stash-an-untracked-file), I tried `git stash -u`. Unfortunately, it deleted everything, and I can't find any way to get it back! `git stash apply` doesn't work. The files aren't even in the recycle bin. Is there anything I can do at this point?

[It turns out that this is a known problem](http://blog.icefusion.co.uk/git-stash-can-delete-ignored-files-git-stash-u/), but one that curiously wasn't mentioned in the Stack Overflow answers.

I'm using Git 1.8.1.msysgit.1 on Windows 7.

The output of `git stash list` is

```
stash@{0}: WIP on testing: 50c7eb3 testing
```

Comment: What's the output of `git stash list`?

Comment: @Manuel It's `stash@{0}: WIP on testing: 50c7eb3 testing`, but that's not going to help since the deleted files aren't in the stash.

Comment: looks like a bug then, the `-u` should save non tracked files, it works for me on Linux with Git 1.8.5.3.

Comment: @manuel, apparently the problem has to do with having an untracked but not ignored folder that contains only untracked files.

Comment: yes, tested that too, works ok on my system, maybe you  should update your git.

Comment: @Manuel even if the problem is fixed in later versions, that wouldn't help me. The question here is if there's anyway to recover when it has already deleted your files.

Comment: Fair point, you could check if the files ever hit the internal file system (Git objects): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545232/recovering-files-from-git-objects