# Files missing in Git repository

Tags: git, missing-data

- I made an empty private repository called
  "clonedRepo" .
- Then I cloned the empty repository locally on my machine under the
  folder htdocs.
- Then I dragged a folder called "codebase" that had all the code under
  the cloned empty repo "clonedRepo".
- Then I used the Github app for Mac OS X to commit and push all the
  code under the folder "codebase" to "clonedRepo" but the commit
  failed because a couple of video files were too large which is fair
  enough.
- I clicked the undo commit button.
- But all of a sudden all the files under "codebase" were gone. The
  directories remain but the files are gone.
- I tried "git stash list" for this local repo in the terminal but that
  just returns the default command prompt.

I didn't have backup of this code and its really important to me because I've been working on this since weeks but making it again from scratch will be time-consuming and mundane. Any idea how I could get it back? I didn't delete the local cloned repo or anything inside it. The local repo displays itself as being worth 302 MB but contains visible stuff worth only 46KB. Please help.

Comment: undo commit wouldn't have deleted any files. Are you sure you did not run a `revert` or `reset`? What happens if you type `git reflog` can you paste the result of that command?

Comment: Also try: https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git

Comment: look under your .git folder, this is what taking all your space. Then you can look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545232/recovering-files-from-git-objects) to try to recover from your object directory

Comment: @bitoiu This is the output from git reflog :

46e2eb0 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to 46e2eb01205202cb31e95be55aa1108ba61b2639

c1710f2 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to c1710f200b0265136d0997d3820b36b9fe7a68a1

3af2dc6 HEAD@{2}: revert: Revert "All-to-date"

c1710f2 HEAD@{3}: commit: All-to-date

46e2eb0 HEAD@{4}: clone: from https://github.com/chaitanyaagrawal/ucl-summer-research-internship.git

Comment: `HEAD@{2}: revert: Revert "All-to-date" c1710f2 ` Suspicious. You can try doing `git reset --soft 46e2eb0` and see if that helps. That is the state before the revert.

Comment: @bitoiu Tried doing git reset --soft 46e2eb0 but nothing changed. I am going to try Fredric Henri's answer in the meantime.

Comment: What would you expect? You clicked "undo commit" and the changes of this commit (adding your files) were undone. This is exactly how things should work. To recover: `git log --oneline` --> search for the hash of the commit that introduced your codebase-files --> `git reset --hard <HASH-OF-THAT-COMMIT>`. Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would like to thank @bitoiu , @Fredric & @eckes for their help.

- So basically when I added my codebase to an empty repository and
  committed, the commit couldn't be pushed because a video file in the
  codebase was larger than 100MB. On pressing "Undo the commit" I
  believed I lost all the codebase.
- But actually what happened was it moved to a hidden .git folder
  within the repository.
- To show hidden files under your repository, see this link :
  http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/
- Then type `git reflog` to get present and past hash codes of the HEAD.
- Then type `git reset --hard <hash code of the commit that introduced 
  the files>` to populate all the missing files under your
  repository.More info about `git reset` and on the use of `--hard` can
  be found here : [Whats the difference between git reset --mixed, --soft, and --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245) .